# Cannot totally compile and link cpp project as a static library

Tags: c++, makefile, autotools, autoconf, automake

I have followed this [link](http://mij.oltrelinux.com/devel/autoconf-automake/) and adapted its steps to make it work for my project.

My goal is to create a `libfile.a` to distribute as a static library. The project tree is the following:

```
project
   |
   +-src
      +- <some cpp and hpp files>
      |
      + containers
             |
             +- <other cpp and hpp files>
```

I easily created `configure.ac` file and the `Makefile.am`s. The tree structure changed this way:

```
project
   |
   +- configure.ac
   +- Makefile.am
   +-src
      +- <some cpp and hpp files>
      + Makefile.am
      |
      + containers
             |
             +- <other cpp and hpp files>
```

Now, when I go: `(*)`

```
aclocal; autoreconf --install; autoconf; ./configure
make
```

`.o files` are generated for all the `.*pp files` contained in `src`, but it fails when it starts generating those targets in `src/containers`. So the `Makefile` is not generated properly. What am I doing wrong? Can someone help me?

PS here there are files involved:

```
# --- configure.ac ---

AC_PREREQ([2.68])
AC_INIT([filea], [1.0], [dev@host.net])
AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE([filea], [1.0])
AC_CONFIG_SRCDIR([src/HashFunctions.cpp])
AC_CONFIG_HEADERS([config.h])

AC_PROG_CXX
AC_PROG_RANLIB

AC_CHECK_HEADERS([stddef.h stdint.h string.h])
AC_HEADER_STDBOOL

AC_C_INLINE
AC_TYPE_SIZE_T
AC_TYPE_UINT16_T
AC_TYPE_UINT32_T
AC_TYPE_UINT8_T

AC_FUNC_MALLOC
AC_FUNC_MKTIME
AC_CHECK_FUNCS([memset])

AC_OUTPUT([Makefile src/Makefile])

# --- Makefile.am ---

AUTOMAKE_OPTIONS = foreign
SUBDIRS = src


# --- src/Makefile.am ---

lib_LIBRARIES = libfile.a
libfile_a_SOURCES = \
    ConfigLib.hpp \
    ConfigLib.cpp \
    HashFunctions.cpp \
    HashFunctions.hpp \
    Logger.hpp \
    Logger.cpp \
    Queue.hpp

libfile_a_SOURCES += \
    containers/SafeContainer.cpp \
    containers/SafeInterger.cpp \
    containers/SafeMap.cpp
```

**EDIT 1**
as suggested by [Brett Hale](https://stackoverflow.com/users/906839/brett-hale) the commands marked with `(*)` have been replaced by the following ones:

```
autoreconf -fvi
```

Output:

```
autoreconf: Entering directory `.'
autoreconf: configure.ac: not using Gettext
autoreconf: running: aclocal --force 
autoreconf: configure.ac: tracing
autoreconf: configure.ac: not using Libtool
autoreconf: running: /usr/bin/autoconf --force
autoreconf: running: /usr/bin/autoheader --force
autoreconf: running: automake --add-missing --copy --force-missing
autoreconf: Leaving directory `.'
```

When going with:

```
./configure
make
```

Still no rules are found to generate targets in the subdirectory.

**EDIT 2** I switched to a non-recursive approach (Thanks to [Karel Zak's blog](http://karelzak.blogspot.it/2013/02/non-recursive-automake.html)) and finally I can `make`my lib.

Comment: Can you try using: `autoreconf -fvi` instead of the `aclocal; ....;` commands?

Comment: May I suggest investigating [SCons](http://scons.org), [CMake](https://cmake.org), and other build systems - even plain [make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/) - *anything* but the horror that is `autoconf`/`automake`...

Comment: @JesperJuhl - yes, cmake started out with pure intentions... only to find that it's a *hard* problem, and effectively reinvents the wheel without the 20 years of experience in the autotools - along with a syntax used nowhere else - unlike bash / m4.

Comment: @BrettHale Thank you for answering. Please have a look at EDIT 1 in the question;

Comment: @JesperJuhl Ty for the answer. I prefer investigate a little bit more on autoconf / automake and hopefully, soon or later and with some help, I will figure out how it has to be done.

Comment: @FilippoLauria - It would still be interesting to know why it didn't work. I'm wondering if you haven't made automake aware of the existence of the `containers` directory, e.g., `EXTRA_DIST = containers` in `src/Makefile.am`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still I don't know what I was doing wrong following the typical `recursive approach`; but, finally I made this work, switching to a `non-recursive approach` (as I wrote in **EDIT 2**). [This article](http://karelzak.blogspot.it/2013/02/non-recursive-automake.html) on Karel Zak's Blog helped me a lot!

```
# -- new configure.ac file --
AC_PREREQ([2.68])
AC_INIT([filea], [1.0], [dev@host.net])
AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE([filea], [1.0])
AC_CONFIG_HEADERS([config.h])
AC_CONFIG_SRCDIR([src/HashFunctions.cpp])

AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE([filea], [1.0])
LT_INIT

AC_CANONICAL_HOST
AC_PROG_LIBTOOL
AC_PROG_GREP
AC_PROG_EGREP
AC_PROG_CXX
 ...
AC_HEADER_STDBOOL
AC_C_INLINE
AC_TYPE_PID_T
AC_TYPE_SIZE_T
AC_TYPE_SSIZE_T
AC_TYPE_UINT8_T
AC_TYPE_UINT16_T
AC_TYPE_UINT32_T

AC_FUNC_ERROR_AT_LINE
AC_FUNC_FORK
AC_FUNC_MALLOC
AC_FUNC_MKTIME
AC_CHECK_FUNCS([memset socket])

AC_OUTPUT([Makefile]) # the makefile is only one!
                      # In the subdirectory I have created few
                      # Makemodule.am included in the "main makefile.am"

# --- makefile.am ---
AUTOMAKE_OPTIONS = foreign
lib_LIBRARIES = filea.a

libfilea_a_SOURCES =
include src/Makemodule.am
include src/containers/Makemodule.am # now filea_a_SOURCES is a
                                     # "global variable"
# -- src/Makemodule.am
libfilea_a_SOURCES += \
    src/ConfigLib.hpp \
    src/ConfigLib.cpp \
    src/HashFunctions.cpp \
    src/HashFunctions.hpp \
    src/Logger.hpp \
    src/Logger.cpp \
    src/Queue.hpp

# -- src/containers/Makemodule.am
libfile_a_SOURCES += \
    src/containers/SafeContainer.cpp \
    src/containers/SafeInterger.cpp \
    src/containers/SafeMap.cpp
```

Notice that now, even if `Makemodule.am` files are placed at different levels in the dir tree, whenever a filename is typed in one those modules, it has to be preceded by its relative path. This path is relative to `Makefile` location.